# initialize an vector with a specified number of unitialized space

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

basically I want to be able to do something like this

```
std::vector<int> myInts(3); 
myInts.push_back(1);
myInts.push_back(2);
myInts.push_back(3);
```

Conceptually, I want the vector myInts has only 3 spaces with the values {1, 2, 3}

Apparently,if you run the above code in C++, the result would be  {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3}

One of the main goals for C++ is efficiency, but it seems to me that in the first line of code, assigning 0 to the initliazed vector is unnecessary.

what do you think? is "initialize an vector with a specified number of unitialized space" achievable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a vector with three `0`, then pushing back a further three elements. To instantiate a vector with values 1, 2 and 3, you can do this:

```
std::vector<int> myInts{1,2,3};
```

Alternatively, you can instantiate an empty vector, call `reserve` to avoid re-allocations, and then push back the values:

```
std::vector<int> myInts;
myInts.reserve(3); 
myInts.push_back(1);
myInts.push_back(2);
myInts.push_back(3);
```

The call to `reserve` has the effect of allocating enough space for three elements, without initializing any elements.

Comment: thanks that is bascially what i want, but looks like this cannot be achieve in one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the vector with a size of 3 and you then add 3 additional entries.

as juanchopanza answered, one method is to reserve space for the vector which does not create vector entries yet. So you can't access any reserved but not added entries.

```
std::vector<int> myInts;
myInts.reserve(3); 
std::cout << myInts.at(1) << std::endl
```

should throw 'std::out_of_range'

the other way might be to create (or resize) the vector with a given number of elements and change the wanted entries according to your wishes:

```
std::vector<int> myInts(3); 
myInts[0] = 1;
myInts[1] = 2;
myInts[2] = 3;
```

which way you should choose depends on the way you want to use the vector. If you want to use `.push_back()` for example because you don't know the last manipulated index, you will want to go the `.reserve()` way while the `resize()` way should be used when you want to access any index in the known scope at any time without knowledge whether previous indices were manipulated yet (or if the index is fixed for some data).